# Слово "заяц"

Tags: этимология

В сети мне попадались ресурсы, рассказывающие о происхождении русских названий животных. Но вот, пожалуй, самого известного русского зверя - зайца там не было. Откуда происходит слово "заяц"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наше родное слово, славянское
Восходит к праслав. *zajecb <заяц>,  от  корня*  zaj- <прыгать>

Answer (score 2):

Народ ссылается на Фасмера да на Цыганенко. А они выдумщики, оба не знают, что на Руси зайца КОСЫМ называют. А почему? Да потому что бегает и все время по диагонали путь срезает. Есть глагол такой срезай. Вот его окончание и перешло к зайцу. зает=заец.
 В литовском остался след. Косой - įstrižai, диагональ - įstrižainės.
так что *zaj --прыгать?  это из области фантастики ИЕ -сказочников.

а косой-это русская кривая харя, да к так заяц по-английски и звучит.
косой в баскском-zeiharra.

Answer (score -1):

Может быть от его позы когда встаёт на задние лапки издалека кажется что передними лапами прикрывает или держится за яйца?(Смешно, а вдруг?)

Answer (score -5):

Зяць, зияць - в славянских языках означает "зиять" - это о норе или открытой ране. Вот отсюда и "заяц". Раньше не различали зайцев и кроликов.

Comment: Раньше не различали... Вы-то сейчас различаете?